# How to extract tabular data from a PDF file in Java

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox

I have query about extracting data from PDF files. I have a PDF file with multiple tables of data available. I want to extract data from require table content.

How can I extract tabular data from a PDF file?

How do I do that using iText/PDFBox?

Comment: Is the pdf tagged?

Answer (score 0):

tabula-java is a library for extracting tables from PDF files. It is the table extraction engine that powers Tabula (repo). You can use tabula-java as a command-line tool to programmatically extract tables from PDFs.

Comment: The OP asked to do it with iText and PDFbox, not with any other software.

Comment: Using PdfBox table data extraction, you can refer this page content https://dzone.com/articles/traprange-method-extract-table.

Comment: Your comment about PdfBox should have been an answer on its own. I flagged your answer about tabula-java for deletion, because it does not answer the OP's question.